# Image under Hilbert Transform in $L^1$

Tags: harmonic-analysis

I have a question concerning the proof of following proposition:

**Proposition**:
Let $\phi\in S(\mathbb{R})$ be given. Then $H\phi \in L^1(\mathbb{R})$ if and only if $\int_{\mathbb{R}}\phi(x)dx=0$.

Where H is the Hilbert Transform ($Hf:=\frac{1}{x}\int_{\mathbb{R}}\frac{f(y)}{x-y}dy$)

**Proof**:
Suppose first that $\int_{\mathbb{R}}\phi(x)dx=0=\hat{\phi}(0)=0$. We then use the Fourier Inversion Formula to compute:
\begin{equation}
H\phi(x)=\int_{\mathbb{R}}\widehat{H\phi}(\xi)e^{2\pi i x \xi}d\xi
\end{equation}
Indeed, this first equality is made rigorously because, for $\phi\in S(\mathbb{R})$, we have $H\phi \in L^2(\mathbb{R})$....*The proof continues*.

**My question:** why is $H\phi \in L^2(\mathbb{R})$?

Comment: That's one of the basic results - the Fourier transform of any $L^1$ function is continuous. Trivial from dominated convergence.

Comment: oh... ok! Sorry

Comment: You really shouldn't edit questions in a way that makes previous answers and comments look like nonsense. My previous comment was an answer to a question that has disappeared, so it looks ridiculous. Anyway, regarding the current question: Plancherel.

Comment: Ok @DavidC.Ullrich I'm sorry for this. - But Plancherel just say that the $L^2-$norm of the fourier Transform is the $L^2$-norm of the function itself ... how can I use this fact here?

Comment: What _is_ the Fourier transform of $H\phi$?

Comment: It's $\hat{H\phi}(\xi)=\int_{\mathbb{R}}H\phi(x)e^{-2\pi i x \cdot \xi}dx$ isn't it?

Comment: Only if $H\phi\in L^1$. There's a simple expression for the FT of $H\\phi$ in terms of $\hat\phi$, presumably coming up later...

Comment: Can I get a reference for this proposition? I would like to see this proof.

Answer (score 1):

This is an answer to the current version of the question, which asks why $H\phi\in L^2$ if $\phi$ is a Schwarz function. This is clear from Plancherel.

Except that doesn't work if we don't know yet what the Fourier transform of $H\phi$ *is*; could be the current proof is leading up to that. One can prove it directly from the definition as a convolution:

At least formally, ignoring irrelevant constant factors, $H\phi=\phi*K$, where $$K(t)=\frac1t.$$ Write $K=K_1+K_2$, where $$K_1=K\chi_{[-1,1]}.$$

Now $K_2\in L^2$, so $$||\phi*K_2||_2\le||K_2||_2||\phi||_1<\infty.$$

Define $$\psi(x)=\sup_{|t|\le1}|\phi'(x+t)|.$$You cann use the fact that $\phi$ is a Schwarz function to show that $\psi\in L^2$. On the other hand, $$\int_{-1}^1\frac{\phi(x-t)}{t}\,dt=\int_0^1\frac{\phi(x-t)-\phi(x+t)}{t}\,dt$$ shows that $$|\phi*K_1|\le c\psi.$$

Comment: But actually, why do we need $H\phi$ to be in $L^2$ for the step to be rigorous?

Comment: @MorganeMaPh Two questions per question is my limit, sorry.